# How Can I Remove This White Box Behind This HighCharts Sparkline (Code and Picture Included)

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, highcharts

In the code provided below, you can see that I have a list of data series all with Data and a Name, and for each series in that list, I am trying to create a highcharts sparkline.  The data for the sparkline is bound using KnockoutJS. However, there is this pesky white background square that I can't figure out how to remove (pictured below).

```
var highChartsFunction = $(function () {
            Highcharts.SparkLine = function (a, b, c) {
                var hasRenderToArg = typeof a === 'string' || a.nodeName,
                    options = arguments[hasRenderToArg ? 1 : 0],
                    defaultOptions = {
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: (options.chart && options.chart.renderTo) || this,
                            borderWidth: 0,
                            type: 'area',
                            backgroundColor: '#eeeeee',
                            width: 120,
                            height: 50,
                            style: {
                                overflow: 'visible'
                            },
                            skipClone: true
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        credits: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            labels: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: null
                            },
                            startOnTick: false,
                            endOnTick: false,
                            tickPositions: []
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            endOnTick: false,
                            startOnTick: false,
                            labels: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: null
                            },
                            tickPositions: [0]
                        },
                        legend: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                                animation: false,
                                lineWidth: 1,
                                marker: {
                                    enabled: false
                                },
                                states: {
                                    hover: {
                                        enabled: false
                                    }
                                },
                                fillOpacity: 0.25,
                                color: "#2aabb2"
                            },
                        },
                    };

                options = Highcharts.merge(defaultOptions, options);

                return hasRenderToArg ?
                        new Highcharts.Chart(a, options, c) :
                        new Highcharts.Chart(options, b);
            };

            var $tds = $('div[data-sparkline]');

            function doChunk() {
                var i,
                    len = $tds.length,
                    $td,
                    stringdata,
                    data,
                    chart;

                for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
                    $td = $($tds[i]);
                    stringdata = $td.data('sparkline');
                    data = $.map(stringdata.split(','), parseFloat);
                    chart = {};
                    $td.highcharts('SparkLine', {
                        series: [{
                            data: data,
                            pointStart: 1
                        }],

                        chart: chart
                    });
                }
            }
            doChunk();
        });
```

Here is the html behind the sparklines:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: $parent.series">
            <li>
                <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
                <div  data-sparkline="#" data-bind="attr: { 'data-sparkline': Data } "></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And finally, the picture of the output:

[image]

Is there anyway to remove this white square? I've tried all of the background attributes and the borders and nothing seems to work.  Whenever I add this into JFiddle, the charts look just fine and do not have the white square, so I cannot recreate the issue there in order to isolate it.  Thank you in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: Can you set this up in a fiddle or live page? Have you verified that it's part of the chart? Could very well be the li/span/div

Comment: I agree with @jlbriggs ... it looks from your screenshot that the chart is offset from the white background (to the right and downward by a few pixels).

Comment: Have you tried to disable all your CSS and check if problem appears? It can be caused by padding parameter in your stylesheet.

Comment: Figured it out, it was some CSS within the ul/li.  Changed to div and disabled the css and it works great.  Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score -1):

Hard as there isn't a live example. Try the below though:

```
ul,
ul li  {
 padding: 0px !important;
margin:0px !important;
}
```